# Освобождение памяти потока

Tags: c++, qt

Нужна критика по поводу того как я использую класс потока.
Имею такие файлы:

```
#ifndef SOME_THREAD_H
#define SOME_THREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>

class Some_Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Some_Thread(QObject *parent = 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "Create some thread...";
    }

    void run()
    {
        unsigned int count = 0;
        while(count < 4)
        {
            qDebug() << "Thread is doing something..." << count++;
            this->msleep(500);
        }
    }

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // SOME_THREAD_H
```

Запускаю поток так:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <some_thread.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    Some_Thread *sThread = new Some_Thread(0);
    QObject::connect( sThread, SIGNAL( finished() ), sThread, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
    sThread->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Вопросы к вам, более опытные коллеги, следующие:

1. как быстро очиститься память после выхода из цикла while(count < 4)?
2. Действительно ли очищается память?
3. Должен ли указатель sThread после выполнения deleteLater() указывать на NULL?
4. Как мне использовать этот поток в последствии повторно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как быстро очиститься память после выхода из цикла while(count < 4)?

Есть несколько вариантов - вызывайте непосредственно после выхода с цикла деструкторы, вызывайте деструкторы (явно или неявно) в деструкторе потока или через deleteLater.

> Действительно ли очищается память?

Я не увидел утечек

> Должен ли указатель sThread после выполнения deleteLater() указывать на NULL?

нет. нет смысла. Ну разве что для своей внутренней логики. На утечки в приложении это не влияет.

> Как мне использовать этот поток в последствии повторно?

Точно также - ещё раз создать и запустить.

```
Some_Thread *sThread = new Some_Thread(0);
QObject::connect( sThread, SIGNAL( finished() ), sThread, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
sThread->start();
```

P.S. Конструктор потока я бы писал как минимум так

```
explicit Some_Thread(QObject *parent = 0) : QThread(parent)
```

Comment: и ещё один вопрос в догонку, если я делаю так: QObject::connect( sThread, SIGNAL( finished() ), sThread, SLOT( deleteLater() ) ); насколько я понимаю, то после этого не обязательно делать так: delete sThread;?

Comment: deleteLater сам вызывает delete. Поэто не то что "не обязательно", а категорически "нельзя".

Comment: А при каком условии сработает сигнал SIGNAL( finished() )?

Comment: По факту завершения функции run